# Increase the speed of a delete query which deletes a huge chunk of data?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a delete query that removes a huge chunk of data from a table. The query looks like this

```
While loop

DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id=12345;

End loop
```

This query fetches 1000s of data.

The loop is huge as well as the data being deleted by the query is also very huge. As a result the system becomes very slow. I need a way to optimize it.

Note : storage engine InnoDB

Thanks

Comment: does the whole loop runs in transaction? long transactions in repeatable read isolation level can hurt performance because MySQL have to constantly read the rollback log to fetch the data

Answer (score 0):

This reply is based on the assumption, that the loop isn't responsible for the slow process.

There are several ways to speed `DELETE`-statements up, some are more practical than others. First you have to find out what exaclty slows down the `DELETE`-query, for example many indexes, alot of data rows, maybe a slow hardware - or just a poor connection to the server.

One way would be to use the `QUICK`-option, which handles deleting in the index-files differently. Check out the details for this in the [MySQL-manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html).

Another way would be:

1. Copy your table,
2. Delete your data in the copy
3. Delete the original table,
4. Rename the processed copy to the former filename.

That you separate the deleting from your working table. This ofc shouldn't be done if the table we're talking about here is under alot of traffic, or using foreign keys and such.

Comment: The loop is or any other factor is not responsible for the slow process. The Delete query is slow because it 'Deletes' a huge amount of data.( data in 1000s). Does QUICK work on INNOdb? Regarding the other way mentioned by you, will it work if the table comprises of lakhs of entries and we are trying to delete a few 1000s among it?

Comment: Quick works on INNOdb, too. Without knowing how your table structure looks like and how the application works around it, I can't say for certain how my 2nd approach will affect your program.